# Locale specific date in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, date-formatting

I am trying out jekyll for website creation. I am using jekyll-bootstrap.

The default configuration has the page archive, where all the posts are listed grouped by year and month of the post date. Currently the months appear in English. I've looked at the code and this is an excerpt which is responsible for putting the date:

```
{% capture this_month %}{{ post.date | date: "%B" }}{% endcapture %}
```

I've found a lot of information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats), so there is a way to specify the desired locale. But how can you make jekyll respect it? Simply adding

```
default_locale: "lt"
```

in `_config.yml` naturally does not work.

Answer (score 23):

You can overwrite the current month by using Liquid Date Format:

```
{% assign m = page.date | date: "%-m" %}
{{ page.date | date: "%-d" }}
{% case m %}
  {% when '1' %}Januar
  {% when '2' %}Februar
  {% when '3' %}März
  {% when '4' %}April
  {% when '5' %}Mai
  {% when '6' %}Juni
  {% when '7' %}Juli
  {% when '8' %}August
  {% when '9' %}September
  {% when '10' %}Oktober
  {% when '11' %}November
  {% when '12' %}Dezember
{% endcase %}
{{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}
```

If your date is, for example 2015-02-20, the output will be `20 Februar 2015`

Answer (score 15):

Because i18n is not available on github pages, I built upon [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29757806/48136) of @Kleo Petroff and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32914455/48136) of @Falc, I set up a way to have a date with locale names defined in a YAML file :

The code is almost the same without the whole case statement :

```
{% capture i18n_date %}
{{ page.date | date: "%-d" }}
{% assign m = page.date | date: "%-m" | minus: 1 %}
{{ site.data.fr.months[m] }}
{{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}
{% endcapture %}
```

I set the following data-structure (could be in `_config.yml`, or in some `_data/some.yml` file), in the above code the file is `_data/fr.yml` :

```
months:
    - Janvier
    - Février
    - Mars
    - Avril
    - Mai
    - Juin
    - Juillet
    - Aout
    - Septembre
    - Octobre
    - Novembre
    - Décembre
```

Note that `page.date | date: "%-m"` output the month number as a **string**, ie June number is actually `"6"` not `6`, liquid silently **casts that string to a number** when *piping* the `minus` filter.
During development it was not something I was aware and thus liquid didn't returned anything when passing `m` with the value "6" to `site.data.fr.months[m]`, I only saw the trick when looking at Falc answer.

Answer (score 9):

Use plugin [i18n](https://github.com/gacha/gacha.id.lv/blob/master/_plugins/i18n_filter.rb) from jekyll supported plugins [page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/).

Note that github pages does not support local plugins. See the [related issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/325).

Comment: How can I specify the pt-BR locale? That is, the region part of the locale?

Comment: simply specify "pt-BR" instead of "lt", the list of supported locales is here: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Comment: Liquid Exception: Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. nil given. in _posts/2012-09-15-test.html.evn:ruby 2.0 ,jekyll-newest

Comment: It is a year old answer, maybe something changed.

Answer (score 9):

My turn to share my solution without plugin inspired by the previous ones: 
I've created an include with some parameters like: `{% translated_date.html ... %}`

The idea is to translate the months and days names respecting the format using the date filter syntax (ex: "%A %-d %B %Y"). The strings used for the translation are in yaml files stores in `_data`.

Code and usage available on the repo [oncleben31/jekyll-date-basic-i18n](https://github.com/oncleben31/jekyll-date-basic-i18n/).

Example of integration in my blog with Jekyll sources available in the repo [oncleben31/oncleben31-cc](https://github.com/oncleben31/oncleben31-cc). Look at the layouts `post.html` and `home.html`.

Comment: It works with github pages and is the best solution I found

Answer (score 3):

I started using the [i18n](https://github.com/gacha/gacha.id.lv/blob/master/_plugins/i18n_filter.rb) plugin suggested by @mpictas but when Jekyll regenerates a page it starts to print "error" instead of the localized date. So I removed the plugin and started to use this simple code, similar to the "case/when" solution:

```ruby
{% assign months = "Enero|Febrero|Marzo|Abril|Mayo|Junio|Julio|Agosto|Septiembre|Octubre|Noviembre|Diciembre" | split: "|" %}
{% assign m = page.date | date: "%-m" | minus: 1 %}
{% assign day = page.date | date: "%d" %}
{% assign month = months[m] %}
{% assign year = page.date | date: "%Y" %}
<span class="date">{{ day }}/{{ month }}/{{ year }}</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You also could write an own Liquid filter in a Ruby file like following:

```
module DateFilter
  MONTHS = %w(Januar Februar März April Mai Juni July August September Oktober November Dezember)

  def german_long_month(input)
    MONTHS[input.strftime("%m").to_i - 1]
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(DateFilter)
```

When you put this file into the `_plugins` folder of your Jekyll site you can use the filter in your template file like other filter.

```
{{ post.date | german_long_month }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine @Falc answer with [jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin](https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin):

Simply use in template:

```
{% assign months = "january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december" | split: "|" %}
{% assign m = post.date | date: "%-m" | minus: 1 %}
{% assign day = post.date | date: "%d" %}
{% assign month = months[m] %}
{% assign year = post.date | date: "%Y" %}
<span class="post-meta">{{day}} {% t month %} {{year}}</span>
```

Then in `_i18n/en.yml`, `.../pl.yml`, `.../any-language.yml`:

```
january: January
february: February
march: March
april: April
may: May
june: June
july: July
august: August
september: September
october: October
november: November
december: December
```

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37994328/4416259) of @Brice I came up with this solution to output the month name in Spanish.

```
<p class="post-meta">
    {% assign mes_index = page.date | date: "%-m" | minus: 1 %}
    {% assign mes = site.data.spanish.meses[mes_index] %}

    <time datetime="{{ page.date | date_to_xmlschema }}">
        {{ page.date | date: "%-d" }} de {{ mes }} de {{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}
    </time>
</p>
```

*"Mes" means "month" in Spanish.*

`_data/spanish.yml`

```
meses:
  - Enero
  - Febrero
  - Marzo
  - Abril
  - Mayo
  - Junio
  - Julio
  - Agosto
  - Septiembre
  - Octubre
  - Noviembre
  - Diciembre
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working in a fully automated translations to locale to work on GitHub pages (no plugins), I modified previous answers to this solution as a first approximation of what I need:

```
{{ page.date | date: "%-d" }}
{% assign m = page.date | date: "%-m" | minus: 1 %}
{{ site.data.ui-text[site.locale].months[m] }}
{{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}
```

in _config.yml you can set de default site locale as in my case:

```
locale: "es-ES"
```

in _data I have a YAML file (ui-text.yaml) containing:

```
# English (default)
# -----------------
en: &DEFAULT_EN
  months: 
    - January 
    - February 
    - March 
    - April 
    - May 
    - June 
    - July
    - August 
    - September 
    - October 
    - November 
    - December

en-US:
  <<: *DEFAULT_EN

# Spanish
# -------
es: &DEFAULT_ES

months:
    - Enero
    - Febrero
    - Marzo
    - Abril
    - Mayo
    - Junio
    - Julio
    - Agosto
    - Septiembre
    - Octubre
    - Noviembre
    - Diciembre

es-ES:
  <<: *DEFAULT_ES

# french
# -------
fr: &DEFAULT_FR
months:
    - Janvier
    - Février
    - Mars
    - Avril
    - Mai
    - Juin
    - Juillet
    - Aout
    - Septembre
    - Octobre
    - Novembre
    - Décembre
```